# git ignoring a directory with backslashes in the name

Tags: git

Because the fix is outside of my hands, i need to ignore a directory that is itself named as a path. For whatever reason, on macos, i have a folder that is named `\Users\myname\repos\project\subproject\Logs`. That is not the path to the folder, the folder is literally named that, backslashes and all. That is, the full path would read `/Users/myname/repos/project/subproject/\Users\myname\repos\project\subproject\Logs`. I understand this is an insane way to name a folder, it is not within my control and I would like to ignore it altogether and pretend it does not exist.

However, I am unsure how to refer to the directory correctly in my gitignore. I have the line

```
subproject/\Users\myname\repos\project\subproject\Logs/
```

in my git ignore but it still tracks new files placed in that directory. Do i need to escape the backslashes somehow?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore Backslash is used to escape.  While I don't see it explicitly in the documentation, I would guess double-backslash "\\" would escape the backslash so it was interpreted as a literal backslash.

Comment: Try `subproject/*Logs/` unless you have another directory that matches this.

Comment: @erik258 That works! I had a hunch that might be it, but I too was not seeing it in the documentation and I must have got distracted with other potential solutions

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this can be solved by escaping the backslash like many escape characters `\\` or by utilizing the asterisk, ie `subproject/*Logs/`.

Based on comments from erik258 and balki.